# Type of combinatorial problem

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization, assignment-problem

I'm looking at a problem that looks as follows:
$$
C = \sum_{i =1}^N\sum_{j<i} ( A_{ij} - B_{{P(i)P(j)}} )^2
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are square matrices and $P$ is a permutation matrix mapping all $i \in \{1,...N\}$ to the best permuted indices. I'm thinking it's similar to an QAP, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you really mean $j<i$?  That is, you are going to ignore the upper-triangular part of $A$?

Comment: Hi, yes, but actually the matrices are symmetric. Hence we can also leave this out.

Comment: Well, it can be written as a BIP with assignment constraints and a quadratic objective. I'm hesitant to call it a QAP because that problem has a rather specific form, but it is rather similar.